# Regex Doesn't Know When Url Has Ended

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've just recently found a bug in this regex `'~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?clips\.twitch\.tv/([^&]+)\S*~i',`. When I have two links in a string and one of them comes after doing this regex it includes the second url within the html.

`'~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?clips\.twitch\.tv/([^&]+)\S*~i',` converts to `'<br><iframe width="600" height="315" src="//clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=$1&autoplay=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>',`

If I were to put https://clips.twitch.tv/SparklyGrotesqueStingrayPMSTwin and https://clips.twitch.tv/AbnegateSpinelessWoodcockCopyThis within the same string they get combined together when it embeds so it causes and error. I've tried using `?([?#]+.+)?` which is supposed to check for a trailing slash or not but that hasn't helped. This also happens even if it's not two links. Just any string after the first link.

Comment: You can put the answer here and I can vote it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the twitch urls don't have any trailing characters after the video id, you can greedily capture all visible characters like this:

```
~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?clips\.twitch\.tv/(\S+)~i
```

If they might have querystring data, then you might use:

```
~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?clips\.twitch\.tv/([^\s&?]+)\S*~i
```

If you know that the ids are only alphabetical, you can use this:

```
~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>|<iframe.*?</iframe>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?clips\.twitch\.tv/([a-z]+)\S*~i
```